# Pd.crosstab missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, contingency

I am using pd.crosstab to count presence/absence data. In the first column, I have several presence counts (represented by 1's), in the second column I have just one 'presence'. Howwever, when I run crosstab on this data that single presence in the second column isn't counted. Could anyone shed some light on why this happening and what I'm doing wrong?

Python v. 3.8.5
Pandas v. 1.2.3
System: MacOS Monterey v. 12.5.1

**Column1:**

```
>>> mbx_final['Cmpd1640']
OV745_1A    0
OV745_1B    0
OV745_1C    1
OV745_1D    1
OV745_1E    0
OV745_4A    1
OV745_4B    1
OV745_4C    0
OV22_12A    1
OV22_12B    1
OV22_12C    1
OV22_12D    0
OV22_12E    0
OV22_12F    0
OV22_13A    0
OV22_13B    0
OV22_13C    0
OV86_6A     1
OV86_6D     1
OV86_6E     1
OV86_6F     1
OV86_6G     1
OV86_6H     1
OV86_6I     1
OV86_6J     1
OV86_6K     0
OV86_6L     1
OV86_8A     1
OV86_8B     1
OV86_8C     1
OB1B        1
OB1C        1
SK3A        0
SK3B        0
SK3C        0
SK7A        1
SK7B        0
```

**Column2:**

```
>>> mgx_final['Otu2409']
OV745_1A    0
OV745_1B    0
OV745_1C    0
OV745_1D    0
OV745_1E    0
OV745_4A    0
OV745_4B    0
OV745_4C    0
OV22_12A    0
OV22_12B    0
OV22_12C    0
OV22_12D    0
OV22_12E    0
OV22_12F    0
OV22_13A    0
OV22_13B    0
OV22_13C    0
OV86_6A     0
OV86_6D     0
OV86_6E     0
OV86_6F     0
OV86_6G     0
OV86_6H     0
OV86_6I     0
OV86_6J     0
OV86_6K     0
OV86_6L     0
OV86_8A     0
OV86_8B     0
OV86_8C     0
OB1A        1
OB1C        0
SK3A        0
SK3B        0
SK3C        0
SK7A        0
SK7B        0
```

**Crosstab command:**

```
contingency_tab = pd.crosstab(mbx_final['Cmpd1640'],mgx_final['Otu2409'],margins=True)
```

**Results:**

```
>>> contingency_tab
Otu2409    0  All
Cmpd1640         
0         15   15
1         21   21
All       36   36
```

**I would expect to see a result like this:**

```
>>> contingency_tab
Otu2409    0   1   All
Cmpd1640         
0         15   0   15
1         21   1   22
All       36   1   37
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dropna` parameter, which is by default set to `True`. Setting it to `False` will include columns whose entries are all NaN.

```
contingency_tab = pd.crosstab(mbx_final['Cmpd1640'],mgx_final['Otu2409'],margins=True, dropna=False)
```

You can read more on the official documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

---

Edit 1:

I've replicated your dataset and code and run the following:

```
df_in = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", index_col="index")
mbx_final = df_in[["Cmpd1640"]]
mgx_final = df_in[["Otu2409"]]
contingency_tab  = pd.crosstab(mbx_final['Cmpd1640'], mgx_final['Otu2409'], margins=True)
display(contingency_tab)
```

And I get your expected output:

[image]

There might be something wrong with how you're displaying the crosstab function output.

Comment: Just tried that and no change to the result? I still don't understand why its missing the "1" in column2? Surely that shouldn't be counted as a Nan?

Comment: What's the datatype of the column? (You can check with `mbx_final.dtypes`)

Comment: All int64 for both columns.
>>> mgx_final.dtypes.unique()
array([dtype('int64')], dtype=object)
>>> mbx_final.dtypes.unique()
array([dtype('int64')], dtype=object)

Comment: @SamNmrGoggaRainman I've replicated your data and code, and I get your expected output (see my answer update). There might be something wrong with how you output your crosstab output? Are you running it in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for being such a great help with this! 
I do see that you have handled the data slightly differently - I'm just pointing to different columns in two dataframes for the crosstab, whereas you're slicing the columns out and then pointing to that. I would guess my method is failing somehow. Let me try slicing and see what happens!

Comment: Update: Your route worked but also helped me identify the root problem! I was using  row names as my indices and the indices didn't match, leading to chaos! Thanks again for your help!! :D

Comment: @SamNmrGoggaRainman I would just have both columns in one single dataframe, that'd be better!